# how to append two data frame where one inside function and other outside function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df is empty dataframe and inside function dataframe(df2) formed after some operation,  I want to append these two dataframe df & df2 and should give final output in df3

```
df =pd.DataFrame(columns=['a' , 'b'])

def fun():
       .
       .
   df2= pd.DataFrame({'a': value_1, 'b': value_2})
   display(df2)
   
   df3 = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
   dispaly(df3)

   return df2
fun()
```

output would be
df3
a      b
value   good
value   good
value   bad
value   bad
but while using append or concat there is no output(df3)

Comment: (1) Make the creation and append work in a script without `fun` before you try making the subfunction. (your df2 creation isn't right -- and you've typoed `dispaly`.)  This is good programming practice, to only do one new thing at a time. 
(2) Your last line should be `df3 = fun()`; currently you are returning df2 from `fun`, but not keeping it by assigning it to a variable. The technical term for this is  [scope](https://pythongeeks.org/python-variable-scope/)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the first dataframe as an argument to your function, and assign the result returned from the function to `df3`. Something like this:

```
def fun(df):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': value_1, 'b': value_2})
    return df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a' , 'b'])
df3 = fun(df)
```